# DIY Humidity dome for growing microgreens

Tags: seedlings, greenhouse, urban-gardening, humidity

I am designing a humidity dome for growing microgreens, but need help with deciding on the material and design specifics. I'd basically like to replicate the following product using wire and polyethylene film used for greenhouses.

[here](https://www.bootstrapfarmer.com/products/humidity-dome) is a humidity dome for reference.

For this version, I thought a half-cylinder shape would be easier to achieve using wire.

I'd also like to embed a small 5V fan to the top enclosure, which I'll control remotely to regulate humidity. I thought to add small holes around the perimeter of the dome, so that the fan can pull air out, forcing fresh air into the dome through these holes.

The dome would go over a tray growing microgreens. Tray outer dimensions: 21” x 10.75” x 2.475”. [tray](https://www.bootstrapfarmer.com/products/deep-soil-block-propagation-trays?pr_prod_strat=use_description&pr_rec_id=fd205703c&pr_rec_pid=11333818254&pr_ref_pid=1852952969306&pr_seq=uniform) for reference

**Questions**

- what materials should I be looking for for constructing the body of the enclosure? Is the half cylinder shape a good idea?
- for the polyurethane film, I was thinking to use something like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/VEVOR-Greenhouse-Film-16-ft-x-28-ft-6-ml-Polyethylene-UV-Resistant-Greenhouse-Clear-Plastic-for-Agriculture-PEWSM1628FT000001V0/320584286?g_store=&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D28O-028_023_LAWN_ACC-NA-NA-NA-SMART-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-SMART_SHP_NA&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D28O-028_023_LAWN_ACC-NA-NA-NA-SMART-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-SMART_SHP_NA-71700000063988474-58700005690512855-92700051915081058&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_O2lBhCFARIsAB0E8B_a68yp3lhno2BNnxvSmSGjufdBmllyVM5C_Uu-TqOciPskwy7SH14aAqVmEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)
- is the idea to use the fan to pull air out of the dome as described above good?

thanks!

Comment: As a hack, plastic film will not last nearly as long as a giant inverted hard plastic storage box with a few holes drilled. And a fan will reduce the humidity you seek.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - transparent one

Comment: Is this going to stay inside or out ?

Comment: Was thinking to keep this inside below a grow light. As far as shape, I think a hexagonal shape might be easier to achieve with wire than a half cylinder with a rectangular base like I mention above. Open to comments though

Comment: Perhaps you are going about it the wrong way around. Since you intend to grow this indoors with grow lights, it might be far better to go for a zip up grow tent where humidity and light is in the entire tent and not in individual plastic components. Some tents even have impeller fans and vents but I do not think there is any simple and economical relay system that could turn on impeller or extract fans to control humidity since you are then in the territory of underfloor heating and humidifiers.

Perhaps the idea would be to trial this with a simple shop-bought small seed tray and cover?